# How To Auto-Size the *WIDTH* of a MultiSelect List Box

Tags: c#, css, asp.net-core-mvc

So I've got this tag here:

```
@Html.ListBox("GroupsAvail", null, new { size = 20, width = 1000 })
```

For one thing, no matter how big I make that width number it doesn't get any wider after 500. The groups I'm listing sometimes have names longer than what can be viewed in the box. I need it to auto size to the longest group name. The size is fine at 20, it's the width I'm having so many problems with.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use Inspect Element in your browser then find the style that affects your ListBox since you are using the Html.ListBox it has a default style.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, how would this auto size the width?

Comment: See my edits, it makes no sense to me. I specify 500px and it wants to only do 280px.